# Testing controller new action in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm trying to test my controller's new actin with Rspec but getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:category)).to be_a_new(Category)
       expected nil to be a new Category(id: integer, title: string, image_url: string, description: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Here is the code for the test:

```
describe "GET #new" do
    it "assigns a new category as @category" do
      get :new, params: { }, session: valid_session
      expect(assigns(:category)).to be_a_new(Category)
    end
  end
```

Categories controller new action:

```
def new
    @category = Category.new
  end
```

Using get with the new action opens up a form where a new category can be created.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like your test itself is ok and highlighting an issue - meaning `new` action isn't entered and `@category` isn't assigned. Are you sure that `valid_session` is setting the right credentials for emulating a logged in user?

Comment: @David Thanks, that was it. Didn't instantiate a user for my `session[:user_id] = user.id` which emulates a logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
describe "GET #new" do
    before(:each) do
      session[:user_id] = valid_session.id #or something like
      get :new
    end

    it "should be success" do
      expect(assigns(:category)).to_not eq nil
      expect(assigns(:category)).to be_a_new(Category)
    end
end
```

This way you set the session before get :new.